# Django Admin passing data to change_list_result.html

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

The template change_list_results.html recieves a parameter which is called **results**. It contains every record (in db) in a raw_html for printing it in change_list.html. 
I want to change the view which controls this **results**, for returning into it every value of the recod´s tables (as object) instead of a raw_html within it ( kind of  ).

Someone knows where is this parameter sending to the template?

Thanks mates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. If someone want to know you must to override the inclusion tag called result_list over change_list_result.html. Cheers